# definite integral by parts with discontinuous point

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity

Let $f(x)=\int_1^{x^2} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt$, can we find $\int_0^1 xf(x) dx$? via integral by parts since the function $\frac{\sin t}{t}$ is discontinuous at the point $x=0$.

A possible answer was given as
$$\int_0^1xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f(x) d (x^2)=\frac{1}{2}[x^2 f(x) ]_0^1-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^2 d f(x)=\frac{1}{2}f(1)-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 x^2f'(x)dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 x^2f'(x)dx.$$
and
$$
\int^1_0 x^2f'(x)dx=\int_0^1 x^2 \frac{2\sin  x^2}{x}=\int_0^1\sin x^2 d(x^2)=[-\cos x^2]_0^1=1-\cos 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ has a finite limit at $0$. For this define $g(t)$ as $\frac {\sin t} t$ for $ t \neq 0$ and $1$ for $t=0$. $g$ is a continuous function. Above analysis shows that $\int_0^{1} xg(x)dx=1-\cos 1$. But $ xf(x)$ becomes Riemann integarble if you define its value at $0$ as $1$ and then we get $\int_0^{1}xf(x)dx= \int_0^{1}xg(x)dx=1-\cos 1$.